# Использование GenericRepository, Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Делаю блог. Есть ли смысл использовать GenericRepository для всех сущностей? ORM ef. TDD не используеться. 
Стоит ли его использовать только ради crud операций? Или все же лучше использовать dbSet?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы подразумеваете под `Делаю блог.`

Comment: В учебных целях, для себя.

Comment: я к тому, что с таким описанием задачи, только вам известно, что вам лучше использовать